# Custom Checkboxes in IE8 / IE7

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create custom checkboxes for my website and it works fine with >IE9 and other browsers. But it doesn't work as expected in IE8 or 7. Here is my CSS

```
input[type="checkbox"] + label span {
  height: 13px;
  width:13px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: url("../img/icons.png") no-repeat;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  margin-right: 6px; 
  background-position: -57px -118px; 
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label span{ 
background-position: -70px -106px; 
}

<input type="checkbox" id="chkbox1" value="1" onclick="alert('clicked');">
<label for="chkbox1"><span></span>Checkbox1</label>
```

It works fine in latest browsers and I downloaded `selectivizr.js` for fallback to `:checked` pseudo selectors to work in IE8 / 7 but the problem is that when I click on the checkbox, nothing seems to be happening to the state of the checkbox and even the `onclick` event is not getting captured. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Strange that the onclick event is not firing. Is it possible that the `z-index` is causing an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Like Nash3man said it could be a z-index issue. Personnaly for cross-browser custom checkboxes i use this plugin jquery: http://fronteed.com/iCheck/

Answer (score -1):

Good chance this will work. I created them in two hours. Tell me if it works. I haven't tested them in ie because I don't have an old version of ie available.

Radio buttons:
https://plus.url.google.com/url?q=https://jsfiddle.net/www139/ba5jn2e6/19&rct=j&ust=1438272911487000&usg=AFQjCNGbnoaoAsY0eXLb8k0YBrO3wswiNQ

Checkboxes:
https://plus.url.google.com/url?q=https://jsfiddle.net/www139/wpq6qjyf/76/&rct=j&ust=1438273369508000&usg=AFQjCNG4Tfz0XYteFZAz8Q53OXSevujfNg